# Wireless router error 'cable unplugged'

Tags: networking, wireless-router

I bought a wireless router and set it up, it worked the first time, but I forgot the admin password so I had to hard-reset the router. After that it's unable to connect to my ISP again, it keep says the network cable is unplugged, although it's plugged, and the cable works if I connect it directly to the computer. Couldn't find answers on the internet. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Give some more details, have you tried to change cables, wich router, wich OS? You connect what directly to computer ?

Comment: Seems the Ethernet port itself is cooked, even the router software cannot detect if anything is attached to it, other ports work fine. There are 5 ethernet ports, so I just used a different port and set it up manually. Bullocks!